# How can I solve a compilation error when using ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compiler-errors

Getting following error in the below program, can you please point out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: <any>
    at listdemo.ListDemo.main(ListDemo.java:8)
C:\Users\Savera\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.5\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Savera\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.5\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

The code I am using is the following

```java
package listdemo;
import java.util.*;

public class ListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ArrayList <Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<>(20);
        ArrayList <Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4,5)); //Line 8
        al1.add(10);
        al1.add(0, 25);
        al1.addAll(al2);
        System.out.println(al1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to compile on the command line with `javac`

Comment: Could not replicate the error.